# How to create square shaped legend markers while using geopandas to plot a choropleth map?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, geopandas

I am trying create a legend which will have square shaped markers instead of round markers. I tried to use ".set_marker('s')" and it is adding multiple markers.

Here is my code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18, 10))
europe_gdf_without_russia.plot(    
                    column="percentage_2nd_booster_60plus",
                    cmap='Blues',        
                    legend=True,        
                    legend_kwds={"title":"Percentage",
                                 'loc':'center left',
                                 "fmt": "{:.2f}%", 
                                 'bbox_to_anchor':(1,0.5),
                                },
                    edgecolor='black',       
                    linewidth=0.8,          
                    k=4,                      
                    scheme='quantiles',       
                    missing_kwds={           
                           "color": "lightgrey",
                           "label": "No data",
                            },
                    zorder=1,
                    ax=ax
             )

# Customising the texts in the legend
leg = ax.get_legend()
for count, lbl in enumerate(leg.get_texts()):
    label_text = lbl.get_text()             
    lowe1 = label_text.split()[0]            
    lower=lowe1.replace(',',' -')            
    upper = label_text.split()[1]           
    if count==0:
        new_text = ' <{}'.format(upper)
    else:
        new_text = ' {} {}'.format(lower,upper)  
    lbl.set_text(new_text)                   

leg = ax.get_legend()                       
for ea in leg.legendHandles:
    ea.set_marker('s')
```

I tried to use "ea.set_marker('s')" after getting the legendhandles.

Here is my code:

```
for ea in leg.legendHandles:
    ea.set_marker('s')
```

And the output I am getting:

[image: Multiple-legend-markers]

I want to get a single square shape marker for each line of the legend

Comment: What kind of geometry (Point, Polygon, ...) the geodataframe `europe_gdf_without_russia` has?

Comment: The geometry is consisted of multipolygons of the countries @swatchai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find a keyword argument for `legend_kwds` in `geopandas.plot()` to solve the issue. Though I solved this in a tricky way. After accessing the legend I added the following chunk of code to get the required result. I set the `data` of the legend to 1d array using the suitable positional point. In my case it was (11.,3.85). The purpose of this customise data point is to overlap the built-in legend marker from geopandas. Then make the markersize bigger to fully overlap the built-in legend marker and used `lh._legmarker.set_markeredgecolor('None')` to remove the built-in edge marker colour. Here is the new chunk of code:

```
for lh in leg.legendHandles:
       lh.set_marker('s')
       lh.set_data((11.5,3.85))
       lh.set_markersize(17)
       lh.set_markeredgecolor("None")
       lh._legmarker.set_markeredgecolor('None')
```

Here is the final version of the full code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18, 10))
europe_gdf_without_russia.plot( column="percentage_2nd_booster_60plus",
                                cmap='Blues',        
                                legend=True,        
                                legend_kwds={"title":"Percentage",
                                             "loc":"center left",
                                             "fmt": "{:.2f}%", 
                                             "bbox_to_anchor":(1,0.5),},
                                edgecolor='black',       
                                linewidth=0.8,          
                                k=4,                      
                                scheme='quantiles',       
                                missing_kwds={"color": "lightgrey",
                                              "label": "No data"},
                                zorder=1,
                                ax=ax)
leg = ax.get_legend()
for lh in leg.legendHandles:
           lh.set_marker('s')
           lh.set_data((11.5,3.85))
           lh.set_markersize(17)
           lh.set_markeredgecolor("None")
           lh._legmarker.set_markeredgecolor('None')
```